# Continue insert if error occurs in foreach

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a nested list and I am iterating over it and inserting data into my database, only if all child list items are successfully inserted in database.

You can see my code I am using `try catch` for nested iteration and as well as for outer iteration and whole code is wrapped inside `BeginTransaction.`

This code works fine as long as I provide valid data.

But, if nested iteration failed due to some validation issue `(i.e. SubjectCategoryId not provided )` it exit the inner foreach after doing all iterations, increment the outer foreach, try to perform `SaveChanges` but fails by saying Object Null reference error.

Feel free to ask me if you need to more info. I feel I am missing some minor point especially when dealing with nested foreach inside `BeginTransaction`.

Do you see any issue with my code structure? I am using EF 5

My code:

```
foreach (var student in Student)
{
    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            Student student = new Student
            {
                StudentNo = item.Stu_No,
                Name = item.FullName,
                Description = item.Description,
                Phone = item.ContactNo,
                Address = item.Location
                Status =  item.status
            };

            _context.Student.Add(student);
            _context.SaveChanges(); // Get Object Null reference error for second iteration if child iteration fails. But works fine if no data issue.

             var subjectsInfo = student.Subject_Info.GroupBy(pt => new { pt.Subject_Id, pt.SubjectDesc }).ToList();
             SubjectInfo subInfo = new SubjectInfo();
             SubjectCategory subCat = new SubjectCategory();

             foreach(var subjectInfo in subjectsInfo)
             {
                 try
                 {
                    subInfo.Subject_Id = subjectInfo.Id;
                    subInfo.Description = subjectInfo.Description;
                    subInfo.Id = student.Id;

                    _context.SubjectInfo.Add(subInfo);
                    _context.saveChanges();

                    subCat.SubjectCategoryId = subjectInfo.SubjectCategoryId;
                    subCat.Status = subjectInfo.Status;

                    _context.SubjectCategory.Add(subCat);
                    _context.saveChanges();
                 }
                 Catch(Exception ex)
                 {
                      // catch exception
                 }
             }
        }
        Catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    } 
}
```

My data population:

```
List<Student> Student= new List<Student>();

Student.Add(new Student
{
    BasicInfo = new BasicInfo
    {
        Stu_No = "1",
        FullName = "Steve Adam",
        ContactNo = "12345",
        Location = "XYZ",
        Status = "Active",
    },

    Subject_Info = new List<Subject_Info>
    {
        new Subject_Info() {
        Subject_Id = "1",
        SubjectDesc = "Math",

        SubjectCategoryId = "",
        Status = active
        },

        new Subject_Info() {
        Subject_Id = "2",
        SubjectDesc = "Physics",

        SubjectCategoryId = "",
        Status = active
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your loop variable when you create a new student record:

```
foreach (var student in Student)
{
    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            Student student = new Student...
```

Use a different variable name.

If you

In your inner, subject info, foreach loop you'll need to count the number of successes:

```
foreach (var student in Student)
{
    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            Student student = new Student...

            int numSuccesses = 0;
             foreach(var subjectInfo in subjectsInfo)
             {
                 try
                 {
                   ... code omitted for clarity

                   numSuccesses++; // The very last thing you do
                 }     
                 Catch(Exception ex)
                 {
                  // catch exception
                 }
             }
        }

        Catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    } 
}
```

As you only really want save the records if at least one subject gets inserted you'll need to roll back the insertion of the student record if there were no successes after the `subjectsInfo` loop:

```
if (numSucesses == 0)
{
    // Roll back the insertion of the student record
}
```

Additionally you should only trap those exceptions you can recover from and log the error. Having a general exception handler is usually the sign of a bad design.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  I am going to try it now. Why you suggested to move 'saveChanges' of the student record after inner forEach loop? i need to understand that.How difference it will make? Becuase I assumed / as per knowlede, i need to save student record first / before inner foreach so that i can use student.Id inside inner foreach loop.Hope i am able to explain you my confusing point.

Comment: @simbada you said yourself that you don't want to save the student record  if none of their subject records save, this change accomplishes that.

Comment: my understanding is (correct me if i am wrong), i have to attach student record to context before inner foreach(SubjectInfo..) so i can use/assign student.Id as FK to SubInfo. saveChanges we can move down as you said but not '_context.Student.Add(student);' it has to be before inner foreach.

Comment: @simbada - indeed - I've just realised your mistake. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Appreciated your time. make sense now. Cheers.